# ¿Cómo validar input para que no acepte ceros al principio de texto?

Tags: javascript

Estoy validando un input type="text", y lo que sucede es que mi input acepta ceros al inicio, es decir:

```
01
02
03
007
```

Mi validación en javascript es el siguiente:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function soloNumeros(e) {
   var key = window.Event ? e.which : e.keyCode;
   return ((key >= 48 && key <= 57) ||(key==8))
 }
</script>
```

En el input mando a llamar ese método:

```
<input type="text" name="quantity[]" id="quantity" 
 onKeyPress="return soloNumeros(event)"  />
```

Esa es mi validación, pero al momento de presionar un cero (0) y luego un número mayor a cero éste me lo acepta, y lo que necesito es que no permita escribir ceros al inicio.
Dejo la siguiente imagen acerca de mi duda.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
¿Alguien tiene idea de cómo lo solucionaría?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo lo haría de la siguiente forma:

```js
function soloNumeros(e) {
   var key = window.Event ? e.which : e.keyCode;
   return ((key >= 48 && key <= 57) ||(key==8))
 }
 
 function pierdeFoco(e){
    var valor = e.value.replace(/^0*/, '');
    e.value = valor;
 }
```

```html
<input type="text" name="quantity[]" id="quantity" 
 onKeyPress="return soloNumeros(event)" onKeyUp="pierdeFoco(this)"/>
```

Espero te sirva, saludos !

Comment: Lo intenté, me sigue aceptando ceros al inicio

Comment: Revisa bien tu código y compara con el mío, cuando yo doy click en ejecutar y coloco un 0 al inicio inmediatamente me lo borra.

Comment: Eso hago, lo estoy comparando

Comment: Muéstrame tu código ?

Comment: Sí, claro, este es el código: <input type="text" name="quantity[]" id="quantity" onKeyPress="return soloNumeros(event)" onKeyUp="noCeros(this)" />

Comment: Y el javascript es: function noCeros(e) { var valor = e.value.replace(/^0*/, ''); 
 e.value = valor; }

Comment: Pero cuando al momento de escribir 01, 02, 05 no los borra, y cuando escribo 064 sí borra el cero, pero 01 no borra.

Comment: Es bien extraño, a mi me funciona perfecto desde el primer 0 que coloco, y tienes el código bien

Comment: No lo he borrado, a ver si funciona

Comment: @CamiloVasquez muchas gracias, si funciona, el error que tenía era que no estaba colocando la funcion  noCeros y lo estaba escribiendo en otro lado del archivo y como no encontraba dicha función no funcionaba, pero ya corregí esa parte, y sí funciona el código que me dijiste, muchas Gracias

Comment: Gracias por el post crack me sirvió mucho saludos